# Jmeter + Jenkins scheduled mail: Unable to filter which http req has failed

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Scenario: I have 3 http requests in a jmx file. I need to run the jmx file using Jenkins and send the mail on failure. I have configured everything and its working fine.

Issue/Problem:
- I am unable to filter which http request has failed based upon the mail sent by jenkins. Jenkins only read the jtl file and send pass/fail mail.

How can I know which http request has failed and which is not?

Comment: you can open the jtl file in listener or generate dashboard to see result

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats) of your choice (i.e. [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer)) and configure it to save only `Errors`

   [image: JMeter Listener Save Only Errors]
2. Configure Jenkins to send this `foo.jtl` file (if exists)
3. Recipients will get results file containing errors only.